# VB.NET How to get total hours and minutes in Listbox

Tags: vb.net, datetime, listbox, timespan

Please help! I need to get the total hours and minutes which format is "HH:mm" from ListBox, for example:

```
    11:20
    22:40
    34:00
```

Total:  68:00

I tried to use Datetime and TimeSpan, but it has error :

> "The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar
>   System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."

Here is my code:

```
    ListBox_monthtime.Items.Add("11:20")
    ListBox_monthtime.Items.Add("22:40")
    ListBox_monthtime.Items.Add("34:00")

    'SUM TIMES IN LISTBOX
    Dim MyDateTimeMonthly As DateTime
    Dim MyTimeSpanMonthly As New TimeSpan

    For Each S As String In ListBox_monthtime.Items
        MyDateTimeMonthly = DateTime.ParseExact(S, "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        MyTimeSpanMonthly = MyTimeSpanMonthly.Add(New TimeSpan(MyDateTimeMonthly.Day, MyDateTimeMonthly.Hour, MyDateTimeMonthly.Minute, 0))
    Next

    monthtime_txt.Text = (MyTimeSpanMonthly.Days * 24 + MyTimeSpanMonthly.Hours) & ":" & MyTimeSpanMonthly.Minutes
```

Comment: `"34:00"` wont parse because TimeSpan would portray it as `1:10:00`.  You would be better off leaving them as TimeSpans and just displaying the result in whatever format you need rather than converting to string

Comment: Thanks, but I need the HH:mm format for the final result.

Comment: @Plutonix I tried the following: `Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse("34:00")` and `Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact("34:00", "HH:mm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. I received a `System.OverflowException` for both methods.

Comment: I guess you missed the part about *displaying them in whatever format you need*.  @вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞвєнᴎєƞ of course it does.  If you want to ultimately sum Timespans, the code should use Timespans not strings.

Comment: @Plutonix I think you may have missed the part about *need to get the total hours and minutes* which is the summation of the times listed in a specific format *which format is "HH:mm"*, not formatting an existing timespan's value to a specific format. In order to add a timespan to another timespan, you need a timespan to start with.

Comment: @вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞвєнᴎєƞ As I said, `If you want to ultimately sum Timespans, the code should use Timespans not strings.`  Rather than doing so *after* they have been displayed in some non standard format, they could be kept as a `List<T>` and trivially summed and trivially displayed as they are.  If they are the result of a calculation, the chopping and parsing is *elided*.  Only if there are some sort of import would you have to contend with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help instead:

```
ListBox_monthtime.Items.Add("11:43")
ListBox_monthtime.Items.Add("22:56")
ListBox_monthtime.Items.Add("34:21")

Dim totalHours As Integer
Dim totalMinutes As Integer
For Each S As String In ListBox_monthtime.Items
    totalHours += S.Split(":")(0)
    totalMinutes += S.Split(":")(1)
Next

Dim remainder = totalMinutes Mod 60
totalHours += totalMinutes / 60

Dim totalTime = totalHours & ":" & remainder.ToString("D2")
monthtime_txt.Text = totalTime
```

You would still be casting Strings-Integers though, so I would put that inside a Try/Catch

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a DateTime or a Timespan from a string using an hour value that is greater than 24. You will need to parse the input yourself and convert it to a valid string to be used by `TimeSpan.parse()`.

```
Dim TotalTime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero
For Each item As String In ListBox_monthtime.Items
    TotalTime = TotalTime.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(FormatTimeString(item)))
Next
Me.monthtime_txt.Text = $"{CInt(TotalTime.TotalHours).ToString}:{TotalTime.Minutes}"


Private Function FormatTimeString(TimeString As String) As String
    Dim timeArr() As String = TimeString.Split(":")
    If CInt(timeArr(0)) > 24I Then
        Dim d As Int32 = CInt(timeArr(0)) \ 24I
        FormatTimeString = $"{d}:{(CInt(timeArr(0)) - (24I * d)).ToString}:{timeArr(1)}:00"
    Else
        FormatTimeString = TimeString
    End If
End Function
```